# json.net SelectToken with embedded "."

Tags: json.net

I have json that looks like:

```
myjson = {"queries":{"F.SP": 27}}
```

so with

```
queryResults = JObject.Parse(jsonString)
```

I can do

```
firstToken = queryResults.SelectToken("queries")
```

and get back the LinqJToken

```
{"F.SP": 27}
```

but I'm then stuck, because when I try

```
subToken = firstToken.SelectToken("F.SP")
```

I get Nothing.  I'm guessing this is because JSON.net is looking for a token "F" with subtoken "SP".

I've also tried each of the following, to no avail

```
myToken = queryResults.SelectToken("queries.F.SP")     
myToken = queryResults.SelectToken("queries[0].F.SP")
```

(queryResults.SelectToken("queries[0]") returns nothing, fwiw)

Any ideas?

EDIT: I have verified that the embedded "." is the problem; if I change the original json to

```
{"queries":{"FSP": 27}}
```

I can do

```
queryResults.SelectToken("queries").SelectToken("FSP")
```

no problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't return the token itself, but will return the value (which is probably what you're looking for anyway)...

```
queryResults.SelectToken("queries").Value<int>("F.SP");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have such names in JSON fields:

```
{"queries":{"F.SP": 27}}
```

You may use SelectToken escaping:

```
queryResults.SelectToken("queries").SelectToken("['F.SP']")
```

or

```
queryResults.SelectToken("queries.['F.SP']")
```

Here are more examples with escaping: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenEscaped.htm

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to use SelectToken, how about an index search?

```
subToken = queryResults["F.SP"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonstring);
var fsp = obj["queries"].First().First();
```

Not the most elegant but it gets the value.